# What are the rules regarding player movement in a lineout

Tags: rules, rugby

What are the rules regarding movement of players in the lineout?

I understand that there needs to be minimum distance between the 2 lines and that there needs to be a minimum distance between the lines and the side line.

I'm interested about movement of players for deception reasons.

Moving back and forth, switching places, leaving the lineout etc

Are there any specific rules that suggest what is and is not allowed at this time?

Comment: Have you tried looking for the laws? They're very clearly explained by the IRB, diagrams and images and examples included for clarity. Law 19 is what you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the asker gives no indication of performing basic checks on whether any rules apply, and adequate official resources are easily available that do so, to far greater depth than is possible on SE. Follow-up questions after reading the laws are preferable.

Comment: 1.> You could have just posted a link to the laws as an answer and that would have been helpful. As it happens the reference to the IRB made finding the "laws" much easier and especially the reference to "Law 19". I don't see why you didn't just post this as an answer.

Comment: 2.> I think you need to check the definition of 'off-topic'. My question is about the rules of a sport (Rugby) and this is a site specifically for asking questions about sport. It's not like I asked about Kids Toys or Politics or Fishing or something else..

Comment: @ Rory Becker "teach me the rules" isn't on-topic in the sense defined by the site itself. "I don't get this technicality in the rule/I don't understand this rule after reading it because it's verbose" would not be.

Comment: This seems answerable in a paragraph or two quoted from the Laws, and could probably be then summed up in a few sentences to form a good answer. We have association football questions like this all the time that are equally vague and broad (see [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer) and [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/what-is-the-rule-for-awarding-indirect-free-kicks-inside-a-penalty-box-rather-th) in particular), so I don't see why asking such a question about rugby union football should result in closure of the question.

Comment: Furthermore, anyone can go and research any question themselves, but that's not the point of Stack Exchange sites. Rory has contributed more than enough effort by formulating an answerable question, with a clearly-defined scope (which is far more effort than some questions asked here). If someone googles "movement of players in a lineout" and hits this question as the top result, they've saved ten to fifteen minutes reading a lawbook. That's part of the purpose of this site.

Comment: In the past, [closing a question due to lack of research](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/if-the-pitcher-throws-to-1st-base-to-try-to-get-the-base-runner-out-is-the-runn#comment19667_12860) wasn't a reason to close or be used as a "[super downvote](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12722/ball-goes-through-the-strike-zone-but-the-catcher-doesnt-catch-the-ball#comment19370_12722)." I'm not sure what merits a different perspective here.

Comment: @studro The question is answered far better by the official source than anything Sports.SE could hope to achieve. Seriously, go and look: the diagrams and annotation make it crystal-clear as to what is and isn't okay in a lineout. It's not doable in "a paragraph or two" for the same reason.

Comment: @mastermind_ed see my earlier responding comment. Trying to clear up a nuance or confusion that results from the law's explanation being tertible, okay. Asking for an explanation without looking at the laws, let alone laws with fantastic explanations already? Not to me.

Comment: @Nij Then let's enforce that across the board. I don't have an issue with your perspective, because you have a valid point. I have an issue when this perspective is applied to one question and not applied to other, similarly-flawed questions.

Comment: Indeed, consistency based on reasonability should be the goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [rugby law 19.8](http://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=19.8), here are a few things we need prior to taking the lineout:

- Both teams have same number of players contesting the lineout, who must be in a single straight line
- Both team contestants must be between the 5m and 15m line from the touch line
- Team lines must be 1m apart and the throw must be made straight in that 1m channel

According to [rugby law 19.10](http://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=19.10):

- The jumpers can only jump once the ball is thrown

Now, they move back and forth **because they have combinations**. Playing at my club, the last number of a lineout call gives a combination. For example "Tequila 6 6 8" means it's combination 8 and players have rehearsed that in training.
They would know for example that number 8 means short lineout, therefore a jumper will jump close to the 5m line.
If the number was 5 from the call "2 Echo 5" for instance, the throw would be to the jumper close to the 15 meter line, etc...

You can have as many combinations as you want. When you have a lineout, you need the opposition not to know what you are about to do, hence trying to lure the opposition into believing you are going to throw at the 15m etc when you are going to end up throwing at the 5m line, by moving back and forth, and having weird calls.

As an external note though, everything that you are allowed to do in rugby, or not allowed to do in rugby is described in the rugby laws available online at http://laws.worldrugby.org/.